# Performance on IN clause or inner join with volatile table with Teradata

Tags: spring, teradata, spring-jdbc, sqlperformance

I have a scenario to perform fetch operation for some wildcarded names. wildcarded names can be more than 75k.

**Case 1:**
I have tried IN clause and LIKE, but it doesn't allow more than 2500 parametered names in IN clause using spring jdbc. So, i used parallel async request with every request contains 2500 wildcarded names

```
SELECT NAME FROM DB.TABLE_A
    WHERE NAME LIKE ANY (:wildcarded_names)


Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
paramMap.put("wildcarded_names", wildcarded_names);

SqlRowSet rowSet = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(query, paramMap);

Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

while (rowSet.next()) {
    names.add(rowSet.getString("NAME"));             
}
```

**Case 2:**
Creating Volatile table in teradata, and inserting all the wildcarded names and using innerjoin with LIKE clause

```
SELECT NAME
    FROM DB.TABLE tbl
    INNER JOIN volatile_table vtbl ON vtbl.NAME LIKE tbl.NAME
```

Which one is more efficient and gives better performance?

Comment: Measure... It might even depend on the volume of data. Also the how much the `in` clause can contain on separate values might even depend on the database in use.

Comment: also if you have only a single column you might want to use the `queryForList` method. That saves the overhead of the `SqlRowSet`.

Comment: Only want to select the NAME column? and if you pass ~75k wildcarded_names, how many records do you have in your db?

Answer (score 0):

If you can have up to 75K values, a volatile table will likely be your better option. The optimizer included an enhancement around TD 13.10 to improve IN list performance, but there are still limits. With the volatile table you should include statistics on the PI and join column, if it differs from the PI.